# Why does awk produce different results for division by zero and how can I test for this?

Tags: error-handling, awk, divide-by-zero

I get six different results when dividing by zero in mawk:

```
$ echo | awk '{print -1/0 }' ; echo $?
-inf
0
$ echo | awk '{print 0/0 }' ; echo $?
-nan
0
$ echo | awk '{print 1/0 }' ; echo $?
inf
0
$ echo | awk '{printf ("%i\n", -1/0) }' ; echo $?
-2147483647
0
$ echo | awk '{printf ("%i\n", 0/0) }' ; echo $?
-2147483647
0
$ echo | awk '{printf ("%i\n", 1/0) }' ; echo $?
2147483647
0
```

I get a "success" exit code for each case.

1. Why does this happen?
2. What can I do about it?  Do I **always** have to check for zero divisors before doing a division or is there a way I can rely on awk's error handling and exit codes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using `mawk`, none of `awk`, `nawk` or `gawk` have this behaviour, division by zero is not supported on those.

Your answers are `+inf` for positive infinity, `nan` for "not a number" and `-inf` for negative infinity, all as expected. These are only output when printing a *float*, i.e. with `%.6g` which is the default `OFMT` (default format used for printing numbers).

```
$ mawk 'BEGIN {printf ("%i\n", 1/0) }'
2147483647
$ mawk 'BEGIN {printf ("%f\n", 1/0) }'
inf
$ gawk 'BEGIN {printf ("%f\n", 1/0) }'
gawk: fatal: division by zero attempted
```

When you print explicitly with "%i" you get +HUGE or -HUGE instead, this is converted to an int (signed 32-bit in your case) and printed as + or - (2^31-1).

The usual practice is to *always* check for divide by zero, ideally minimising the number of times you need to check by reorganising your expressions -- divide by zero causes other implementations of awk to simply terminate.

When `mawk` is building it detects the capabilities of your C math library:

```
$ ./configure
[...]
checking handling of floating point exceptions
    division by zero does not generate an exception
    overflow does not generate an exception
    math library supports ieee754
```

You can get "standard" behaviour if you build with `NOINFO_SIGFPE` defined:

```
$ ./configure CFLAGS="-DNOINFO_SIGFPE"
$ make clean && make
$ ./mawk 'BEGIN {printf ("%f\n", 1/0) }'
mawk: run time error: division by zero
    FILENAME="" FNR=0 NR=0
```

(though this isn't documented, it may not be something you should rely on).

Answer (score 3):

After trying different AWK "dialects" I came to the following conclusion:

Trying `awk`:

```
echo | awk '{print -1/0 }' ; echo $?
```

I am getting:

```
awk: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted
2
```

Trying `gawk`:

```
echo | gawk '{print -1/0 }' ; echo $?
```

I am getting:

```
gawk: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted
2
```

Trying `mawk`:

```
echo | mawk '{print -1/0 }' ; echo $?
```

I am getting:

```
-inf
0
```

If I were you, I would try to identify your "default dialect" (`awk --version`) and I would try to use another dialect like `gawk` and read the exit status in order to understand what happened.

PS: I am running Ubuntu 11.10.

PS: In my case `awk` is an alias for `gawk`.

Comment: `gawk` appears to be the only version that has a `--version` option.  `mawk` uses `-W version` and the default awk I *was* using (Ubuntu default) was `mawk`.  I'm beginning to think that `gawk` might become a standard part of new installs.

Comment: I got some problems with `awk` due to limitations, that is why I am using `gawk` and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

it's not even that hard to  find combinations where even gnu gawk exhibits different behavior depending on calling flags :

(these tests are also more fool-proof since the output is *only* based behavior of which awk/start-up opton is being called, instead of parameter constants that can be manually overwritten.

the gawk notations i've used myself
(GMP/MPFR are self-explanatory) -

> ```
> E = -e aka standard call
> S = -S `—-sandbox`
> P = -P `--posix`
> c = -c `—-traditional`
> n = -n `--non-decimal-data`
> ```

```
    #  (-nan):x:gawk-S/c/E/mpfr
    #  (+inf):x:gawk-n/P
    #  (+nan):x:gawk-GMP/GMP+mpfr
    #   ( 0 ):x:nawk
    #   (inf):x:mawk
    #   (nan):x:mawk2

      x = -log((log(0)*log(0))^-log(-0))/(-"0xABCD")^-!-"";

    # (+nan) :gawk-GMP/MPFR
    #        (NaN:mpfr_log())
    #  (nan) :nawk/mawk/mawk2
    # (-nan) :gawk-E/P/c

        x = log(log((-log(0))/-log(0)));

    # (-inf):nawk
    #  (inf):mawk/mawk2
    # (+inf):gawk-ALL

        y = log(log((-log(0))^-log(0)));

    # (-inf):gawk-GMP
    # (-inf):nawk
    # (-nan):gawk-P/E/c
    #  (nan):mawk/mawk2

        z = log(-log(1))-(-"")^-!-"";

    # (+nan):gawk-GMP
    #  (inf):mawk/mawk2
    #  (nan):nawk
    # (+inf):gawk-except-GMP

        z = log(-log(0))-(-"")^-!-"";

    # (-inf):nawk/gawk-GMP
    #  (inf):mawk/mawk2
    # (+inf):gawk-except-GMP

        z = -(-"")^-!-"";

    #  (inf):nawk
    #  ( 0 ):gawk-GMP
    # (-inf):all others

        xn = (-"")^-!"";
```

these examples may not be exactly just division by zero, but it does highlight that at the edge cases, their behavior varies rather wildly. here's a collated table to make it easier to follow :

```
    a = log(log((-log(0))^-log(0)));
    b = log(log((-log(0))/-log(0)));;
    c = -log((log(0)*log(0))^-log(-0))/(-"0xABCD")^-!-"";
    d = log(-log(0))-(-"")^-!-"";
    e = log(-log(1))-(-"")^-!-"";

/usr/local/bin/nawk  ::  -inf ::  nan ::   0  ::  nan :: -inf ::
---------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/bin/mawk  ::   inf ::  nan ::  inf ::  inf ::  nan ::
---------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/bin/mawk2 ::   inf ::  nan ::  nan ::  inf ::  nan ::
---------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/bin/gawk -e:: +inf :: -nan :: -nan :: +inf :: -nan ::
/usr/...,/gawk -l mpfr:: +inf :: -nan :: -nan :: +inf :: -nan ::
/usr/local/bin/gawk -S:: +inf :: -nan :: -nan :: +inf :: -nan ::
/usr/local/bin/gawk -c:: +inf :: -nan :: -nan :: +inf :: -nan ::
---------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/bin/gawk -P:: +inf :: -nan :: +inf :: +inf :: -nan ::
/usr/local/bin/gawk -n:: +inf :: -nan :: +inf :: +inf :: -nan ::
----------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/bin/gawk -M:: +inf :: +nan :: +nan :: +nan :: -inf ::
----------------------------------------------------------------
```